# Can you identify these Bionicle sets?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, bionicle

Also, I have a box of parts. If I display the heads, will that lead me to what these are?

[image]
[image]

Thanks for any help. My grandson loves to put LEGO parts together so I want to take these apart and have instructions for him.

Comment: Can you post any photos that show more detail?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you have pretty much a jumbled mess of pieces instead of actual sets. You may want to go on ebay and look for bionicle sets that both say complete and that say with manual/instructions

The top image:
The torso is from the black toa ignika
The back silver spines are from spinax from the Maxilos and Spinax set
The two curled spiked silver pieces on the weapon are from one of the barraki sets
The mask is from Onua of the Mistika variety
The one upper leg armor piece is from a black piraka
The bottom two are similar in the way that they come from many sets, nothing complete sadly

Answer (score 2):

The two Bionicles on the right are for sure a mix of different parts from different sets, and, without seeing much close-up details, it will be very difficult to tell you which original sets the parts came from. The white piece on the foreground is part of an Exo Force set from 2006 called 7700 Stealth Hunter (https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7700-1).

[image]

The set on the left might largely consist of pieces from one specific Bionicle, but I have not been able to identify him yet. However, the whole idea behind the Constraction sets like Bionicle and Exo Force is that you can combine them and make your own creations, which seems like what you have here. Your grandson should have a blast playing with them, no matter if they belong to a set or not. Have fun!

Comment: The one on the left is also a mix. Head of [Onua Mistika](https://brickset.com/sets/8690-1/Toa-Onua), torso and legs of [Nuparu Inika](https://brickset.com/sets/8729-1/Toa-Nuparu), arms, spines and weapons from [Maxilos and Spinax](https://brickset.com/sets/8924-1/Maxilos-and-Spinax), and some Barraki teeth, a Phantoka wing, possibly a Piraka leg armor piece, and some feet pieces from other sets.

Answer (score 0):

that's Onua Mistika and he looks about 70% complete

Comment: From all of the [Onua](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=onua#T=S) perhaps you've meant this [Toa Onua](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8690-1) in mind? IMHO, it doesn't look similar to posted picture.

Comment: The feet, legs, weapon and the spikes are definitely different. Arms seem to match and the mask might as well, but it's hard to see.

Comment: yes it's that one but mixed